# Can we schedule a bounded source in flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, apache-kudu

I am new to Flink. I have to create a pipeline where I have to configure a bounded kudu source and an unbounded Kafka stream and then join it. Also periodically I need to rerun the kudu source to refresh the bounded data. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Does Apache Kudu only support batch queries, or can you run a continuous query to get new/modified rows?